# Can we embed authorization for twitter, linkedin, facebook, buzz in asp.net c# web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, authentication, social-networking

I want to implement authorization using social networks like twitter, facebook, Linked In. How can I authorized with all social networks into my asp.net C# web application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, but the authorization process in it's core will still be linked to the APIs of the services you're working on, depending whether such endpoints are available.

Here are some docs you might want to check out:

- [Facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)
- [Twitter API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554643/Authentication)
- [LinkedIn API](http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1008)

Once you have an authorization token, you can access some basic user information (e.g. username or nickname) and link it to your website.

Comment: Is any third party service to combined all the services for authentication ?

Comment: There are layers that allow you to simplify the process, like RestSharp (http://restsharp.org/) that carry an OAuth wrapper.